# ApacheDS autostart failed in CentOS 7

Tags: centos-7, ldap, apacheds

I installed ApacheDS on CentOS 7, but it doesn't start when the system boot and I should start it manually, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming :

- you got ApacheDS .rpm from the [official download page](http://directory.staging.apache.org/apacheds/download/download-linux-rpm.html)
- you did a clean installation with `sudo yum localinstall apacheds-<version>`.

CentOS services are located under `/etc/init.d/`. By default ApacheDS service name takes the version number with it which is not very convenient, so you may first want to rename it in order to make future interactions easier, for example :

```
mv /etc/init.d/apacheds-2.0.0.AM25-default /etc/init.d/apacheds
```

Restart the service to check it works : `service apacheds restart` or `systemctl restart apacheds`.

Now, in order to enable apacheds service to be started on bootup, there are two (almost) equivalent options, either using systemctl (recommended), or chkconfig :

- `systemctl enable apacheds`
- `/sbin/chkconfig apacheds on`

See also [systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd), [chkconfig](https://linux.die.net/man/8/chkconfig)

Comment: I have done all above but dont work yet:
`● apacheds.service - LSB: Start and stop ApacheDS
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/apacheds; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2019-07-29 17:58:34 +0430; 1 day 19h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1783 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/apacheds start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
 Memory: 0B
systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop ApacheDS...
su[1913]: (to apacheds) root on none
apacheds[1783]: Starting ApacheDS - default...
systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop ApacheDS.`

Comment: Because of another problem, I had to reinstall all of the software again, and I installed ApacheDS with `yum` behalf of `rpm -ivh`. Now it works fine for me, THX